# What does Colored dot in systemd means?

Tags: systemd

[image: Colored dot]

I was mainly looking for a way to show what cause my system to slow up booting, and then came up across this. Now I'm curious to know what it means.

Comment: You might find `systemd-analyze blame` to be more useful if you are investigating a slow boot. But for a snapshot of the current situation, `systemctl list-dependencies` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

[From the systemctl man page.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)

> The dot ("●") uses color on supported terminals to summarize the unit
> state at a glance. Along with its color, its shape varies according to
> its state: "inactive" or "maintenance" is a white circle ("○"),
> "active" is a green dot ("●"), "deactivating" is a white dot, "failed"
> or "error" is a red cross ("×"), and "reloading" is a green clockwise
> circle arrow ("↻").

Comment: I then imagine red dot is the same as red cross.

Comment: is there any flag to request a text description of the unit state in the systemctl list-units output? Running sed to convert a bunch of ansi color codes into text seems... silly.

Comment: re my own question in the comments: `--plain` omits the non-ascii characters from the output, nice. however the information about state and dependency tree appears to also be removed.